# jQuery Mobile - Caching Issue maybe?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Can anyone familiar with jQuery mobile help me - (I have done developed this, its my first time using jQuery mobile and I am running in to lots of issues): http://vnbenny.com/other/john/2

when I click the lotto results in the li to take me to the next page, the next page loads but the controls on the page such as (pagination and adsense) dont work.

They work when I refresh the page. Is this a result of caching?

Comment: Show your js code pls.

Comment: its quite a lot, you can view source on page if you don't mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Ajax for transition between pages. When using Ajax for paging transitions, jQuery Mobile injects only the contents of the response's body element (more specifically the `data-role="page"` element). This means that nothing in the head of the loaded page will be used (with the exception of the page title).

When navigating through Ajax, the scripts and styles included in the `head` tag of the loaded pages won't execute unless the page is requested via HTTP. This explains why your page works after a full page refresh.

I suppose that you have added JS files inside the head tag of your second page and these files are not executed. Try to move your script from your second page `head` tag and place it inside the page's div (`<div data-role="page" id="second-page">`) or create a common JS file and load it on the first page's load.

I hope this helps.